# Branch Deep Linking not working when opening app through AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, branch, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Hie, I am using branch for deeplinks in my iOS application. 
If the app is installed, the deeplink opens up and the app and shows a different view controller than the initial view controller. 
If the app is not installed, the user is redirected to AppStore.

Branch's documentation says that if the app is redirected to AppStore we can still send it certain parameters.(like normal) But it isnot working. When app opens after appstore install (after redirection to appstore), it doesnt open the new view controller it opens normally through Branch;s deeplinking (when app is already in iPhone).

My code is as follows :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isDataSynced")
    UserDefaults.standard.setSecret(securePassword)
    //        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "DeviceIdentifiersSavedInDB")
    CommonFunctions.sharedCommonFunctions.setUpSideMenu()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "fromBranch")

    Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) { params, error in
        // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
        // params will be empty if no data found
        // ... insert custom logic here ...
        if error == nil {
        print(params as? [String: AnyObject] ?? {})
            if let parameters = params as? [String : AnyObject] {
                if let link = parameters["~referring_link"] as? String {
                    if self.validateURL(url: URL(string: link)!) {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "declinedTermsConditions")
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "fromBranch")
                        let initialViewController = self.mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomSideMenuControllerViewController") as! CustomSideMenuControllerViewController
                        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: udiBarcode) == nil {
          } else {
        //Navigate to DashBoard VC
        let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomSideMenuControllerViewController") as! CustomSideMenuControllerViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set( "true" , forKey: "isFirstTimeAutomationTest")
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    return true
}


 func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
         Branch.getInstance().continue(userActivity)
        return true
    }


 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        // pass the url to the handle deep link call
      Branch.getInstance().handleDeepLink(url)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: There are people from Branch team monitoring questions in StackOverflow. May want to open Branch support ticket to have more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branch has an amazing support. They answer your every Query.After all the discussions i had with them on mails. I figured out where was the loop hole in my deeplinking using branch.

The link we were sending from our backend included **backslashes(**) while branch accepts **ampersands (&)**. When we replaced our backslashes with ampersands it started working.

Comment: can you please share any tutorial, how to use this. As I am confused about how we can open the AppStore when the app is no installed through deep linking.